# twitter status update using tweetsharp oauth preview 17

Tags: twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

I am trying to update the status using tweetsharp oauth preview 17.

Please let me know how ?.

I tried this code

var msg = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
          .AuthenticateWith(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret, Session["token"].ToString(),            Session["tokensecret"].ToString())
          .Statuses().Update("Hi");

but didn't work.

--Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you submit the request?  If so, what did you get back as response?

```
//continuing your code
var response = msg.Request(); 
var status = response.AsStatus(); 
if ( status == null )
{
   var error = response.AsError(); 
}
```

if you add that code, let me know what you get back for response, status, and (if applicable) error, and I should be able to help.

Comment: Jason, The code i posted worked. The reason why it didn't post before is...my application is registered as read only, changed to read write. 
Also i used your code to know the message status. Thanks Jason